# Apparent power in exponential form

Tags: power, phasor

On page 2 of [this PDF](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-061-introduction-to-electric-power-systems-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_061S11_ch3.pdf), a voltage source \$V= |V| e^{0}\$ is connected to a load \$Z = |Z| e^{j\psi}\$. Then, the apparent power is described as
$$ 
P + jQ = \frac{ |V|^2 }{2|Z|} e^{j\psi}
$$
However, I think the power should be
$$ 
P + jQ = \frac{|V|^2}{|Z|} e^{-j\psi}
$$

Where did the extra factor of \$2\$ and the positive \$j\psi\$ come from? Is this is a mistake in the PDF, or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean page 2?

Comment: yes sir it's page 2. Sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complex power \$S\$ is defined as

$$S = P + jQ = \frac{1}{2}\vec V \vec I^* = \tilde{V} \tilde{I^*}$$

where \$\vec V\$ is a *peak* phasor voltage and \$\tilde{V}\$ denotes a *rms* phasor voltage; the relationship between rms phasors and peak phasors being

$$\tilde{V} = \frac{\vec V}{\sqrt{2}} $$

*Carefully* note that the complex power is (proportional to) the product of the voltage phasor and the *conjugate* current phasor.

Now, Ohm's Law for phasors is

$$\vec V = \vec IZ$$

Thus, for a circuit element with impedance \$Z\$, the associated complex power is

$$S =  P + jQ = \frac{1}{2}\vec V \vec I^* = \frac{1}{2}\vec V \frac{\vec V^*}{Z^*} = \frac{|\vec V|^2}{2Z^*}$$

For \$\vec V = |V|e^0\$ and \$Z = |Z|e^{j\psi} \$, the complex power is

$$S =  P + jQ = \frac{|\vec V|^2}{2Z^*} = \frac{|V|^2}{2|Z|e^{-j\psi}} =  \frac{|V|^2}{2|Z|}e^{j\psi}$$

See that, when we conjugate the impedance, the sign of the phase changes from plus to minus.  Then, since the (conjugate) impedance is in the denominator, we factor out the phase by bringing to the numerator with yet another sign change from minus to plus.